# Two different memory errors depending on where I allocate the memory

Tags: c, memory-management

For my C program I have tried to allocate memory for a double array(ssi) which I then access in another function (spslicer). If I allocate this memory before I call a different function (kpmdos) which should be unrelated I get the error:

`*** glibc detected *** ./SpecSli.ex: double free or corruption (!prev): 0x0000000000a86e40 ***`

and if I allocate it after I get the error:

`` malloc.c:3830: _int_malloc: Assertion `(unsigned long)(size) >= (unsigned long)(nb)' failed. ``

Based on this I think that I did something wrong in kpmdos when I allocated the memory but I cannot see anything wrong:

```
void kpmdos(csptr A, int Mdeg, double nvec, double ctr, double wid, int n, double *mu){

  // initialize variables
  double *w = malloc(n*sizeof(double));
  //free(w);
  fill_rand(n, w);
  double *v = malloc(n*sizeof(double));
  divide_array(w, norm(w, n), v, n);

  double *vkm1 = malloc(n*sizeof(double)); 
  fill(n, 0, vkm1);
  double *vk = malloc(n*sizeof(double));
  memcpy(vk,v, n*sizeof(double));
  double *temp = malloc(n*sizeof(double));
  double *vkp1 = malloc(n*sizeof(double));
  double thet = pi/(Mdeg+1);
  double a1 = 1/(Mdeg+2.0);
  double a2 = sin(thet);
  double jac;
  double scal;
```

Then I do some other coding with no memory allocation.

```
  free(w);
  free(vkp1);
  free(vkm1);
  free(temp);
  free(vk);
  free(v);
}
```

The output using valgrind when it is allocated before the function is:

```
> > ==7045== HEAP SUMMARY:
> ==7045==     in use at exit: 46,452 bytes in 235 blocks
> ==7045==   total heap usage: 351 allocs, 116 frees, 66,700 bytes allocated
> ==7045== 
> ==7045== LEAK SUMMARY:
> ==7045==    definitely lost: 22,331 bytes in 146 blocks
> ==7045==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
> ==7045==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
> ==7045==    still reachable: 24,121 bytes in 89 blocks
> ==7045==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
> ==7045== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
> ==7045== 
> ==7045== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
> ==7045== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

Please let me know if you know the problem or if you need more information.

Comment: Try to run `valgrind` tool to find the exact place where you double free or where you overrun the memory.

Comment: And you're sure you never write out of bounds anywhere? Maybe you should try memory-debugging tools such as [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)?

Comment: Teh heap stuffen in your 'other coding'

Comment: ==6493== LEAK SUMMARY:
==6493==    definitely lost: 22,331 bytes in 146 blocks
==6493==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6493==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6493==    still reachable: 24,121 bytes in 89 blocks
==6493==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6493== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==6493== 
==6493== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==6493== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)

Comment: Do not add important information or formatted output in comment, please *edit your question* to include that information instead. Also please show the *complete* Valgrind output, as it probably shows some more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your help. I finally figured out most of it. During my coding which I did not post I had a function which would change all the variables in an array to something different and for this function I was inputting the wrong array size.